# Is .Callback the right way to mock a void-returning method using Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I would like to unit test an Add method in a repository that returns void. I'm interested in testing the actual adding of elements without hitting the database (not whether Add was called or not). Is this the correct way?

```
var list = new List<Foo>();
var repo = new Mock<IFooRepository>();

repo.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<Foo>()))
            .Callback((Foo f) =>
            {
                list.Add(f);
            });

repo.Object.Add(new Foo { FooId = 1 });

Assert.IsTrue(list.Any(x => x.FooId == 1));
```

Comment: It looks like you want to test that something gets added to an internal list.. Ok.  If you are using mocks here why not give your class a fake database instead?

Comment: With that code you're just checking that Add method was called in a very complex way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the only thing you're testing here is Moq itself. You could try mocking the underlying layer, e.g. ISession if you're using Nhibernate.